# Codeigniter Can Not Login Into Administrator After being Uploaded To Hosting

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, login-script

I developed a website using codeigniter, it works normal at localhost.
after I uploaded into hosting, I can not login into administrator page.
always redirect to login page.
no error messages.
If I login by empty username and password, error messages appear.

[login by empty username and password][1]

[login by username and password][2]

**UPDATE** 
**SOLVED...**
**The problem is PHP version at hosting not supported.
So they upgrade their php version, and everything run smothly**

Comment: Have to ask... have you actually added an administrator to your database on the server?

Comment: **Warning:** Don't use `sha1()` for password hashing. It's very insecure. Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead. If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I _really_ hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to get the same functionallity.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). Use CI's DB-class consistently instead of executing some raw SQL queries with unescaped user data.

Comment: Yes I have added manual an administrator id into database on server, but it does not work

Comment: How did you set the password for admin user? Did you put the hashed string in database for the admin password that you are trying to login with?